# Github incorrectly recognizes programming language used in the project

Tags: c++, github, d

So I have a [git repository](https://github.com/gferrin/STMC-C) that I wrote in C++, but github insists that I'm using D. Why is this and is there someway to correct it?

Comment: +1 I was always wondering why/how GitHub gets it wrong.

Comment: Where exactly does it say so?

Comment: @Nawaz if you have the new github it will show up as a big yellow bar across the page. Click on it and it will say D 98.9%

Comment: When we are at it, I'm always wondering where in [my code](https://github.com/griwes/ReaverOS) github found Objective C...

Comment: You sure it's not a grade?

Comment: (Just kidding, just kidding)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Github](https://github.com/) uses it's own language parsing module and sometimes (actually often) it makes faults. Just write more code to make it easier for parser to choose what your main language is and after some time github will get it right.

In this particular case code parser is fooled by your files in `STMC-C/Assignments/a*` dirs with `.d` extension. That's an extension for D sources. The number of this sources dominated in your project so github decided that the main programming language used is D.

edit: Just found [this](https://github.com/github/linguist) public repo (github language detector) - it has some explanations of the system.

Comment: that makes sense though it seems silly still because there are significantly more files with `.cpp` extensions, and as the project consists of several thousand lines of exclusively c++ code I'm not sure if there is anything to be done about it.

Comment: @Loourr A simple find/cat/wc shows your `.d` are 160259 lines in your repository, out of 163404 lines total. You've got 8 `.d` files each consisting of 20000 lines, that's massively more than your C++ code. (Yes, I realise those `.d` files don't contain code.)

Comment: @hvd good point, I think what I'll do is just add them all to my `.gitignore` file, because there all computer generated anyway

Comment: @hvd - check out [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/). FWIW, `find -exec wc -l {} +` would be simpler, and give more info. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

You could create a file `.gitattributes` to set GitHub's Linguist [overrides](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides).

To set your C++ files to be detected as C++ by extension:

```
*.h linguist-language=C++
*.cpp linguist-language=C++
```

To ignore generated files and don't show them in diffs:

```
generated/*.d linguist-generated=true
```

Also, you can mark some files as undetectable, if the language is not on the [known languages](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml) list:

```
*.t linguist-detectable=false
```